# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BLOCK_UNSAFE_POLYMORPHIC_BASE_TYPES Issue when upgrading spring batch 3.0.10 to 4.3.8

Tags: migration, spring-batch, upgrade

I am using spring-batch-core version 4.3.8 and jackson-databind version 2.13.4.2.

Application build is successful, when I deploying it in jboss eap version 7.1.1 getting below errors.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BLOCK_UNSAFE_POLYMORPHIC_BASE_TYPES
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:119)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:192)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:133)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:95)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)

Anyone help to resolve this issue?